# Can Touch ID be used to allow many people to use the same iPhone?

Tags: ios, keychain, fingerprint

I have a requirement where the same iPhone is shared among a small set of people.

Is there an iOS API that allows me to determine who unlocked the phone, so that I can create a user-specific display of my application?

Answer (score 4):

Nope, can't be done. All you know is that the Touch ID succeeded or not.

Keep in mind that an iOS device with Touch ID has no concept of a user. You can simply register several different finger prints. None are tied to a specific person.

Comment: Please see the release notes here, seems like iOS9 allows for something... http://stackoverflow.com/q/34640878/328397

Comment: @LamonteCristo I've looked at those notes and the reference docs for `LAContext`. I don't see anything that allows this.