# How can I tell if a different finger was used to unlock an iOS phone?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xamarin, touch-id

The [iOS 9 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS9.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016198-SW1) indicate that a second (or subsequent) unlock with the same finger will return a value.  This is useful for determining if an iPhone may be [shared among different users.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32997460/328397) ... and adapting PIN codes as necessary.  (for example, a mother sharing a phone with a child, both are touch enrolled)

From the release notes:

> Support for reusable Touch ID matches. A match from the previous phone unlock can be used by evaluateAccessControl: and evaluatePolicy:localizedReason:reply:.

How can I leverage this to detect a new login?

I think the core issue I'm having is that I'm using Xamarin, and perhaps not interpreting the code correctly.

Comment: There is no such method as `evaluateAccessControl:` and there is still nothing in the `LAContext` class that gives you any info other than success or failure.

Comment: @rmaddy seems like there is a method here: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/LocalAuthentication.LAContext.EvaluateAccessControl/p/Security.SecAccessControl/LocalAuthentication.LAAccessControlOperation/System.String/System.Action%7BSystem.Boolean/Foundation.NSError%7D/